# Can we have an easy shorthand to reference SE blog posts?

Tags: feature-request, reference

I find myself linking often to a specific [SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). This one is fairly commonly linked as a close reason and for a number of other reasons. Is there a way we can get an easy shorthand to link to it and other SE blogposts? in this instance I would love to see it be [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective].

Comment: Evernote. ~ ~ ~

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard markup to turn comment links into readable text.

If you enter

`[Good Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)`

the text of the comment will look like this

[Good Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: I know this. However I'm looking for an alternative to looking it up every time I reference it.

Comment: @wax welcome to my world on Programmers :)

Comment: @Wax eagle: Ah, no. There is nothing like that nor is there likely to be. You would have to go to the blog post to assure an *exact* title match for it to work, so it would be just as easy to enter the URL markup. And blog posts/titles can be editing after the fact so that would break everyone's shortcut links. I could see a feature that a blog post URL cold be automatically "oneboxed" where a raw URL could be automatically converted to the post title, but that would still require you to go look up the URL.

Comment: @Robert thankfully its the first google result for "Good Subjective Bad Subjective" :P. Hopefully it stays that way

Comment: @wax eagle: I find it easier to *start* at http://blog.stackexchange.com and search from there. Guaranteed results.

Answer (score 2):

There exist a number of services which create short URLs.

I have created **http://tinyurl.com/stacksubjective** for http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

It's reasonably easy to remember and a little easier to type and get right than all those digits and hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

I use this a lot:

> Welcome to C.SE.  When you get the chance, I'd invite you to check out our [about] and to learn [how we are different](http://tinyurl.com/csediffernt) than other sites.

Per suggestions above, I've created a link http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent

(that is /csedifferent ) to make that easier.